# How to install ament_cmake_python?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html) I discovered that the following package is available:

```
ament_cmake_python
```

but doing:

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake_python test_interfaces
```

I get the following error:

```
ros2 pkg create: error: argument --build-type: invalid choice: 'ament_cmake_python' (choose from 'cmake', 'ament_cmake', 'ament_python')
```

How do I get the ament_cmake_python package working?
The [link](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/tree/master/ament_cmake_python) to github doesn't contain any installation instruction.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382198/how-to-install-ament_cmake_python??/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2021-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is:
there is no possibility to create a package with that option `ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake_python test_interfaces`

You can add `ament_cmake_python` in the `package.xml` file and nothing else...

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2021-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0